# Strange Inbox Behaviour

Tags: bug, notifications, inbox

Is it just me, or there more people that feel that the inbox behaviour is kind of strange.

It seems that I miss some comments referenced to me and cross talk with other stack sites also doesn't seem to work properly...

**EDIT**
Here is an example:

I got an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/169829/19341), but there was no notification. 
[image]

Scanning the inbox was also fruitless...
[image]

It seems to miss.

Comment: Could you be more specific? For example, can you provide examples of comments that should have notified you but didn't? Perhaps also a screenshot of your inbox would help.

Comment: What @ZevChonoles said. Without you giving any specific examples, we have no chance to find and fix possible issues.

Comment: My only complaint is that if I have notifications and view one of them, it marks all the others as read too, so I sometimes miss reading those.

Comment: Also, sometimes old notifications will reappear (even though they have already been addressed). This seems to be common if one uses the back button, but it happens in other instances too.

Comment: I found this post at meta.SO: [Temporarily deleted answer missing from asker's inbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126658/temporarily-deleted-answer-missing-from-askers-inbox). But it's improbable that this is the reason for the behavior described in the post.